# Dell XPS 13 (9350) not charging

Tags: dell, power-management, xfce, 17.04, tlp

I just noticed that my Dell XPS 13 with Xubuntu 17.04 is not charging above ~60%. It charged from 60 t0 62% in one hour. The AC adapter is cold (it gets quite hot usually). Power manager shows perfectly sane numbers [image: XFCE Power Manager screenshot]
What's the problem here? Maybe there is some option that tells it to keep the charge low?

**Update**

I installed TLP, started it and switched to battery mode by typing `sudo tlp bat'. It doesn't help.

Comment: it seems like a kind of conservation mode problem. Xfce power manager itself could be the reason.

Comment: Yeah, I found out that windows 10 shows this amount of charge as 100%. Dell's firmware doesn't fully charge the battery to extend ifs lifetime.